Does llamaindex hybrid search use a reranker?
LlamaIndex (based on OpenSearch) offers the option to use a hybrid search algorithm which should include a mix of both lexical and semantic search.
The vector store class definition is in this file and you can see that one of the options is HYBRID search.
Usually, when you have two different search systems, you would use a reranker (for example a cross encoder) in order to rank the results from the two systems before presenting them to the user. However, on the LlamaIndex website I could not find any documentation on rerankers; if I open the search bar at the top right of the screen and search for reranker, a few tutorials come up for how to implement one, but there is no information as to whether LlamaIndex is using one in their hybrid search.
Does anybody know if they use one, and if not, how they combine results from lexical and semantic search when using a hybrid search approach? Any sources to their official documentation discussing the topic would be very much appreciated.
